# How to calculate dimension of weight matrix for a vanilla RNN

Tags: self-study, neural-networks, linear-algebra, recurrent-neural-network

Sorry if this is kind of a dumb question but I'm taking the NLP course from Andrew Ng on Coursera and I don't understand how to arrive at the correct answer for a question pertaining to calculating the dimensions for the weight matrix of a simple RNN.
[image]

Comment: Since this is a question about the course material you should add the "self-study" tag. Otherwise the question might get closed.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius Thanks for the heads up, this is my first question so I was not aware of the proper etiquette. Thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions of **h** superscript **t** won't change which is (4, 1), so **h** superscript **t-1**  will have the dimensions (4, 1) too, **x** superscript **t** has (10, 1) dimensions, when **h** and **x** are concatenated, you will get (14, 1) dimensions.

the output (**h** superscript **t**) should have the exact dimensions as **h** superscript **t-1**, therefore the weights matrix should have the dimensions (4, 14) in order for the dot product to work out.

**(4, 14) @ (14, 1) => (4,1)**